# How to read pdf file to a text file in a proper format using Spire.PDF or any other library?

Tags: c#, pdf, ocr

How can I read pdf files and save contents to a text file using Spire.PDF?
For example: Here is a [pdf file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7bx9nd4g9eexfkb/101395a.pdf?dl=0) and here is the [desired text file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p8nkuuecaegwgt4/sample.xml?dl=0) from that pdf

I tried the below code to read the file and save it to a text file

```
PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
doc.LoadFromFile(@"C:\Users\Tamal\Desktop\101395a.pdf");

StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

foreach (PdfPageBase page in doc.Pages)
{
    buffer.Append(page.ExtractText());
}

doc.Close();
String fileName = @"C:\Users\Tamal\Desktop\101395a.txt";
File.WriteAllText(fileName, buffer.ToString());
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(fileName);
```

But the [output text file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4c73mhlkm4fkw0z/101395a.txt?dl=0) is not properly formatted. It has unnecessary whitespaces and a complete para is broken into multiple lines etc.

How do I get the desired result as in the **desired text file**?

Additionally, it is possible to detect and mark(like add a tag) to texts with bold, italic or underline forms as well? Also things get more problematic for pages have multiple columns of text.

Comment: You are sharing personal data (names and e-mail addresses) of existing people in your question. Please avoid doing this, unless you have the explicit consent of these people to use that data.

Comment: As @Tamias pointed out too, text from a PDF file might or equally might not be extractable this way. If you want to have something that work in the majority of cases, you should look for OCR.

Answer (score 3):

Using `iText`

```
File inputFile = new File("input.pdf");

PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(inputFile));

SimpleTextExtractionStrategy stes = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
PdfCanvasProcessor canvasProcessor = new PdfCanvasProcessor(stes);
canvasProcessor.processPageContent(pdfDocument.getPage(1));

System.out.println(stes.getResultantText());
```

This is (as the code says) a basic/simple text extraction strategy.
More advanced examples can be found in the documentation.

Comment: Please have a look at the OP's *desired text file*, he wants something much more pre-interpreted, e.g. with paragraph recognition...

Comment: @JorisSchellekens What namespaces do I need to import for the code to work..also, it does not look like it solves the problem of paragraph recognition and bold, italic etc detection and write it to the text file.

Comment: As mentioned by other posters, if the original PDF does not have tagging (which most PDF documents don't), then you will not be able to extract any structure information.

Answer (score 3):

Use **IronOCR**

```
var Ocr = new IronOcr.AutoOcr();
var Results = Ocr.ReadPdf("E:\Demo.pdf");
File.WriteAllText("E:\Demo.txt", Convert.ToString(Results));
```

For reference https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/ocr/

Using this you should get formatted text output, but not exact desire output which you want.

If you want exact pre-interpreted output, then you should check paid OCR services like **OmniPage capture SDK** & **Abbyy finereader SDK**

Answer (score -1):

That is the nature of PDF. It basically says "go to this location on a page and place this character there." I'm not familiar at all with Spire.PFF; I work with Java and the PDFBox library, but any attempt to extract text from PDF is heuristic and hence imperfect. This is a problem that has received considerable attention and some applications have  better results than others, so you may want to survey all available options. Still,  I think you'll have to clean up the result.

Comment: If one happens to have a tagged pdf, the output can be more structured if your text extractor supports tagging information.

Comment: I have tried different libraries like iTextsharp, pdfium.sdk and here is a youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A5H9wpywAtI which shows how to zone an area and extract text  (which is exactly what I want), but I cannot figure out how the video creator added the **draw custom rectangle** to the windows form to zone the area to read, can anyone at least help me with that...?

Comment: I'm not saying that PDFBox is necessarily the best library for this purpose, but I feel compelled to praise their examples and the remarkable helpfulness of the people on their email forum. And their quickness to fix or improve things once pointed out to them.

Comment: This answer should rather be a comment.

Comment: im not sure if your question was answered but we use iText here, and its pretty powerful. We mainly use it for reading PDFs to write other PDFs but its pretty easy to read in PDF components and get the text within

Answer (score -1):

Try BitMiracle.Docotic.Pdf dll, Gives you a proper txt file with formating..

please refer : https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35349222)